# Using debugger to find integer values

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging

For this assignment I am supposed to use the debugger in Visual Studios, I kind of understand how to use it but i cant figure it out completely. For the first part of the code, it asks for all values of a,b, and c. I put my debugger to start right before it starts and then right after it ends. I run it through using the F10 key. I go through it once and I get a=6, b=3, c=6. Then once I go through it again i get different values, however I want to view those values as a list. Is that possible?

```
//THIS IS THE CODE.
 #include<stdio.h>

void func1(int a, int b, int c)
{
  //Track all values of a, b, and c

  printf("%d %d %d\n",a,b,c);
  a = b + b;
  printf("%d %d %d\n",a,b,c);
}

int func2(int x)
{
//Track all values of x

 printf("%d\n",x);
for (x = 7; x < 12; x += 1)
 {
 printf("%d", x + 10);
 }

 return(x);
 }

int func3(int x)
{
 x = x + 51;
return(x);
}

int main()
{
 int a,b,c;
//Track each array index value
 int arr[5];
a = 7;
b = 3;
c = 3;
func1(5, 3, 6);
func2(c);
b = func2(c);
for (c = 0; c < 5; c += 1)
{
  arr[c] = c + 2;
}

 for (b = 22; b > 7; b += -1)
 {
  arr[b + func3(a)] = a + b + c;
  printf("%d\n", b);
 }

 for (b = 0; b < 5; b += 1)
{
  printf("%d\n", arr[b]);
}

 return(0);
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean "view those values as a list"? Do you want to add different value to one array(Multidimensional Arrays) or others? So you could visit the array directly in debugging window like watch or others.

Answer (score 1):

```
 arr[b + func3(a)]
```

Before debugging further fix the bug in the code.

Here you have array out of bound access which will lead to undefined behavior.
You are trying to access `arr[22 + x]` where as the size of the array is 5.